# How resize the Action Bar Menu Text Size in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am developing the android application. have one doubt regarding reduce the text size for action bar menu item. this my code.

```
<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">#888888</item> <!-- 
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> -->
    <item name="android:textSize">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: text size should be in `sp` not in `dp`

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044370/reduce-menu-items-width-height-and-textview-size)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `dip` try with `sp`

Check this Answer for better understanding.

- [Why should we use sp for font sizes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7107974/1160282)

check the following code :

```
<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">#888888</item> <!-- 
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> -->
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
</style>
```

Code adopted from this link. [Changing text Size of menu item in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25130915/1160282)

Comment: Won't this set the font size for the entire application?