# Android Bottom Navigation View item text color?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-menu, android-bottom-nav-view

I Started working on Android Bottom Navigation View. But i am facing one issue. If i added 5 items to bottom navigation view, only selected items showing item text. If i added 3 items it is working fine. Any one please tell me how to show the item text  for all the 5 items.
Thank you in advance.

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.reloadapp.reload.activity.IconTabsActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_40"
        android:title="Home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_40"
        android:title="Profile"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/reload_40"
        android:title="Reload cash"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_musi"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/notifications"
        android:title="Notifications"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_mus"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_40"
        android:title="More"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

dependency:
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/textColorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_icon_tabs"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove animation in bottom navigation ,use this code

```
navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        disableShiftMode(navigation);
```

method

```
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

you can change menu text size like this [How to change the Menu text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844064/how-to-change-the-menu-text-size)

Comment: it is working but i have two large text items. those are not aligned properly :(

Comment: @kartheekij you should not give large text in BottomNavigation.. it's not designed large text items

Comment: can we change the text  size of menu  item

Comment: bro i answered ur question ,if u need more items means use bottom tab with scroll ,accept my answer :)

Comment: @kartheekij if you reduce the size., it will affect the visibility

Comment: @Keerthivasan present the text was little bit large. so tell me how to chnage the text size :)

Comment: @kartheekij answer updated to change the text size in menu items

Comment: @kartheekij if you annwer is really helped you, you should accept and upvote answer

Comment: I followed your code and successfully disable the shift animation. But still, the size of navigation icons slightly changed when checked (and also the size of corresponding text), how to disable that? Thanks a lot!