# Tabs are not get symmetrical in BottomNavigationView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-icons, bottomnavigationview

[image]

> navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_clock"
        android:icon="@drawable/time"
        android:title="" />

    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_medicine"
        android:icon="@drawable/medicine"
        android:title="" />

    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_user"
        android:icon="@drawable/users"
        android:title="" />

    <item android:id="@+id/navigation_setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/setting"
        android:title="" />

</menu>
```

> activity_mail.xml BottomNavigationView component

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp" android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

> when I added 3 tabs BottomNavigationView got symmetrical.but when it's come to 4 tabs BottomNavigationView not symmetrical.how can I solve that? I really appreciate your suggestions.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a vector xml or a drawable png?

Comment: I'm using drawable png for icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove the default animation for BottomNavigationView**

```
navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        disableShiftMode(navigation);
```

method

```
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
```

source https://stackoverflow.com/a/43491890/5423894

Comment: You saved my day.Thanks you for this awesome answer.