# Reduce Menu items width,height and textview size

Tags: android, menu, android-menu

I had done a menu overflow items.I need to reduce menu items width,height and textview size.

I referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897071/how-to-change-size-of-titles-text-on-action-bar).But it is not working for me.I am posted the code and screenshot related to that:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:icon="@drawable/down"
        android:title="Read"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add2"
        android:icon="@drawable/down"
        android:title="write"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/add3"
        android:icon="@drawable/down"
        android:title="bold"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        />
</menu>
```

**Menu Item Screenshot:**

[image]

**styles.xml:**

```
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/down</item>

    </style>
```

My only problem is,I need to reduce the width,height and textview Size in menu items.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can reduce the height and text size of the menu items with the help of below codes:

**res/values/styles.xml:**

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
 
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/PopupMenuTextView</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
 
        <!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Item Height & Property -->
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingRight">5dp</item>
    </style>
 
    <!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Divider Property -->
    <style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
    </style>
 
    <!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Text Size and Text Size -->
     <style name="PopupMenuTextView" parent="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">5sp</item>
    </style>
 
     <!-- Change Overflow Menu Background -->
     <style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">#888888</item>
    </style>
 
</resources>
```

Add the above codes in styles.xml(v11) and styles.xml(v14).

**For More Detail:**

Refer [Action Bar Overflow Menu Customization](http://scriptedpapers.com/2014/08/12/android-action-bar-overflow-menu-customization/comment-page-1/#comment-1551)

Comment: Are you also able to change the overall window width?

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh with the help of above code I reduced text size then width will be decrease

Comment: How to change width?

Comment: There is no option to change the width of popup menu

Answer (score 9):

use this :

```
<item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">72dp</item>
```

Example:

```
 <style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/dropdown_bg</item>
       <item name="android:itemPadding">25dp</item>
       <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">70dp</item>


    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks @Heena.. I wasted my whole day for this.

Answer (score 4):

In style.xml add this

```
<item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">35dp</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingRight">5dp</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option I think is to use meny item action layout.

app:actionLayout="@layout/my_custom_layout"

and then infiltrate it.