# How to customize overflow menu's width?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I want to modify width of overflow menu.
But I dont know how to access the overflow menu.

I tried to

[How can I change popup item width size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469792/how-can-i-change-popup-item-width-size/21618167)

[Reduce Menu items width,height and textview size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044370/reduce-menu-items-width-height-and-textview-size)

But I could not modify the width.

**res/menu/custom_actionbar_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_search"
       android:title="@string/search"
       app:showAsAction="never"/>

   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_menu"
       android:title="@string/setting"
       app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

**java/source**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_actionbar_item, menu);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean shorten width. Also whats xml data to do with design ? if i understand correct?

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar sorry. "shorten" means reduce a width of item.