# android menu item text and auto caps disable

Tags: android, android-studio, menuitem

Currently getting menu item text color back and caps letter for lollipop devices

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_list"
        android:title="@string/list"
        android:actionMenuTextColor ="@color/paytm_blue"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

**To achieve** : item Text color in blue and caps disabled

Thank you in advance

Comment: Checkout this easy solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31535908/3713763

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to one of your values xml files -

```
<bool name="abc_config_actionMenuItemAllCaps">false</bool>
```

Comment: will xml should I add this , can you pl. provide me a clear insight on this

Comment: Value `XML` contains multiple files, in which file I should add this line of code and which block.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom layout for menu item and can set all required things in this custom file.
First create one xml layout file named customemenu.xml

customemenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SHOW ALL "
            android:id="@+id/tvall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search_res, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_list);
        item.setActionView(R.layout.customemenu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```